# Move UITableView row to new position programatically Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm looking to move an item in a tableview to a new position. I have `models` acting as my data source.

```
var models = [Model]
var dataTableView = UITableView!
```

A model class looks like this

```
class Model {
  timestamp: Int64
  ...
}
```

The `models` data source is sorted by `timestamp`, any item inserted should be in it's right position.

When an item's timestamp changes, I want to move it to the corrected sorted position.

What's the best way to do this?
I'm considering just sorting the array to get the item to it's correct position then find it's index and do the following

```
beginUpdates()
reloadRows(at: [INSERTED_ITEM_INDEX, OLD_INDEX], with: .bottom)
endUpdates()
```

So that by reloading both index paths, both cells will display correctly.
Another option would be to find which index the item will occupy if inserted into the list (without actually touching the list) and then do the following:

```
beginUpdates()
moveRow(at: ORIGINAL_INDEX, to: NEW_INDEX)
reloadRows(at: [ORIGINAL_INDEX, NEW_INDEX], with: .bottom)
endUpdates()
```

Which is the better approach?
None? would be happy to learn new approaches, thanks :)

Comment: I'm no expert with table views (and their data sources) but my thoughts start with a question: exactly how *many* rows are in the array? Basically, you need to (a) update the array and (b) resort it somehow, then (c) reload the table view somehow then (d) possibly scroll it. While rather simple - and straightforward - with an array of say 20 or 40 (just sort by timestamp and use `reloadData`, if you are talking about either (1) 20,000 rows or (2) using something stored in the cloud you'll quickly run into all kinds of issues.

Comment: @dfd the array isn't so large, never more than say, about 200, will usually be about 50 items. One requirement is to avoid reloading the entire tableview so the user doesn't see a flash. Which is why I'm looking to only reload only the necessary cells